# restrict access to other pages except home page in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am developing a Django application. This application has a lot of functionality. So I broke down each functionality into sub-functionality and implemented in each individual app. And I used ajax, javascript to display the result in my home page when the form is submitted instead of redirect to my sub-functionality app page.

But the user can access the sub-functionality app page through URL. I want to restrict the user from accessing the sub-functionality app page in this way.

Here let me explain with one of my sub-functionality the **calculator**

My main page has the template and all the forms in it for each sub-functionality. So one of the sub-functionality is a calculator

**calculator view**

```
def index(request):
calculated_result = do_calculation(request) # claculation logic
return JsonResponse(calculated_result)
```

**claculator urls**

```
app_name = 'calculator'
urlpatterns = [  
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='calculator'),
]
```

my javascript code for getting information from the calculator URL and display it on my home URL

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#calc_form').submit(function(event){
      console.log(event);
        event.preventDefault()
        $.ajax({
            url:'/calculator/',
            type:'POST',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            success:function(response){
                $('#output_box').html(`${response.result}`);
              }
        });
    })
})
```

When the user submits the form on the main page, the control goes to the calculator view performs the calculation and displays it in calculator URL, but my js script blocks the redirect and gets the results and displays in my home page. The user can still access the calculator page through URL like `website/calculator/`. I want to restrict access in this way.

**Project urls**

```
urlpatterns = [    
    url(r'^home/', include('home.urls')),   
    url(r'^calculator/', include(('calculator.urls', 'calculator'), namespace='calculator')),
]
```

I looked into `login_request` from **Django decorators** but it's no use because my website is open to all users.

Comment: instead of posting to calculator/, just  POST to home/ , and remove the calculator/ from the urls list. and move the calculator view code to home view

Comment: or you can check if the request is a GET request and redirect the user to homepage when the user tries to go to calculator/

Comment: Use `if request.is_ajax()` in your `get/post` else return 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi just use a view decorator

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def index(request):
    calculated_result = do_calculation(request) # claculation logic
    return JsonResponse(calculated_result)
```

If you go in GET, you will have an error `django.http.HttpResponseNotAllowed` (405) returned

Docs is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/topics/http/decorators/)

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped.